# Auto reconnect to server if server is closed or crashes

Tags: android, connection, server

I have a service that connects to a server. This service is a backup to Google notifications. I have written the client in C# and now I would like to do something similar in Android.

This is the code for the C# client that catches the exception if the server is closed, get the time of the exception and tries to reconnect for five minutes, if it is over five, then it stops trying to reconnect for  5 minutes and then tries again. It seems to be working great

Code:

```
 catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("CONNECT " + e.Message);
                if (attempts == 0)
                {
                    connect_time = DateTime.Now;
                    interval_time = connect_time.AddMinutes(1);
                }

                    double minutes = DateTime.Now.Subtract(connect_time).TotalMinutes;


                    if (minutes < 5.0 )
                    {
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);


                        attempts++;

                    }
                    else
                    {

                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300000);
                        continue;
                    }


                    resetConnectionEvent.Set();

            }
        }
        while (!stopConnections);
```

Now I would like to do something similar for Android. The thing is I don't have a ManualResetEvent in Android and this is a service. Here is my code for Android as of now:

```
class connectSocket implements Runnable
{

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        do
        {
        try
        {
            IsRunning = true;

            SSLContext context = SSLContext.getDefault();

            socket = context.getSocketFactory().createSocket(SERVERIP, SERVERPORT);

            SSLSocketFactory sf = SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();

            sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

            socket2 = (SSLSocket) sf.createSocket(socket, SERVERIP, SERVERPORT, false);

            HostnameVerifier hv = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier();

            SSLSession s = socket2.getSession();




            Intent text_intent = new Intent("Text_view");


            //
            String MACAddr = Utils.getMACAddress(SocketServiceController.this,"eth0");
            if (MACAddr.length() == 0)
                MACAddr = Utils.getMACAddress(SocketServiceController.this,"wlan0");
            if (MACAddr.length() == 0)
                MACAddr = Secure.getString(SocketServiceController.this.getContentResolver(),Secure.ANDROID_ID); 
            System.out.println("************" + MACAddr);
            //
            out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket2.getOutputStream())), true);

            out.write("0002:" + MACAddr + "\r\n");
            //

            //

            out.flush();

            try
            {
                InputStream inputstream = socket2.getInputStream();

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputstream));


                readObject = reader.readLine();

                String text = "";

                while(readObject != "")
                {
                    text = readObject;


                    createNotification("Alert", text, SocketServiceController.this);



                    sendBroadcast(text_intent);

                    readObject = reader.readLine();
                }
                connection_attemp = 0;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

                IsRunning = false;
                createNotification("Alert","Connection is Closed", SocketServiceController.this);
                stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SocketServiceController.class));
                IsRunning = false;
                if(connection_attemp == 0 )
                {
                    c = Calendar.getInstance();
                    connect_time=c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);


                }
                double minutes = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)- connect_time;

                if(minutes < 5.0)
                {

                     connection_attemp++;
                     System.out.println("MINUTES: " + minutes + " CONNECT TIME: " + connect_time);
                     Thread.sleep(5000);

                     System.out.println("CONNECTIO ATTEMPT : " + connection_attemp);
                }
                else
                {
                     System.out.println("SLEEPING");
                    Thread.sleep(15000);

                }
                 System.out.println("STARTING NEW SERVICE");

                        startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SocketServiceController.class));

            }





        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();

            IsRunning = false;

            try
            {
                if(IsRunning != false)
                    socket.close();

            }
            catch(IOException e1)
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        IsRunning = false;
        }
        while(!IsRunning);
```

I have seen some questions on StackOverflow about using a semaphore but I'm not familiar with it and if it would work in this situation. Right now when I run this code it somewhat does what I want but I creates multiple connections instead of the just 1 like it does when I start the service the first time. And just for clarity here is my OnStartCommand:

```
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

     Runnable connect = new connectSocket();

     if(IsRunning == true)
     {

     }
     else
     {
         new Thread(connect).start();
     }

     return START_STICKY;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I don't think you need a semaphore, semaphores would be used if you need to manage more than one connections and you need to ensure that those connections are not executed at the same time.

For the second point, all the code of the run method is inside a do-while loop, that is the reason why several connections are created, you have to put all the configuration of your socket outside the loop, the inner catch block is the one handling the server reconnection, that should be the only part where you use a loop.